# CRM 2011: Lookup in HTML Web Resource

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Can a lookup be used in an HTML web resource?

I have replaced the command of the "Convert to Case" button on the email entity.
It now opens up an html web resource on click.
I need to show lookup fields to Customer and Subject.

Is there an alternative to a lookup for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding lookups to your own page is definitely a pain since they don't 'provide' you with a control to add it to your HTML resources.  I am also not aware of any toolkits that are readily available.

A possible solution for displaying subjects (assuming you don't have too many) would be to use a HTML select element and populate it with the possible values.

As far as the customer goes, it will most likely take some creativity or elbow grease to replace since most likely you have too many accounts/contacts to display in a HTML select.  One thought is you are most likely converting an e-mail with a contact or account already in the e-mail (from or regarding fields).  You can try and pull all the accounts and contacts from the e-mail fields and allow the user to select one of those via radio, select, etc.

If something like that doesn't work then most likely you will need to create your own lookup, or something similar like a text box with an inline grid that gets filtered like a lookup so you don't have to recreate the entire dialog experience.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was thinking of incorporating JQuery UI, which I might do for similar situations in future; for now I created a custom entity that has all the look-ups that are needed. The "Covert to Case" button will open up a new entity form of the custom entity and populate it with fields from the email. The ribbon will be customized to show only a few buttons relevant to creating the new Case.